# Tkinter - Configure a grid properly: why some widgets don't appear?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, frame

I'm trying to design an interface in Python using Tkinter. The interface should be divided into five rows. In each of these row, a button or a frame/label frame shold be accomodate. In the case of a frame/label frame row, other widgets will be hosted. So I decided to define a frame that will act as a container of buttons and frames/label frames, and configured in 5 rows of equal weight. Then I added a label frame at row=0 and a button at row=1. Why only the button appears?

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

# %% ROOT
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("710x630+410+100")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.resizable(1,  1)
root.title("myGUI")
root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# %% EXTERNAL FRAME
ExtFrame = tk.Frame(root)
ExtFrame.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
# ExtFrame.configure(bg='blue')
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)


# %% RESULTS FOLDER LOCATION
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.LabelFrame(ExtFrame)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.grid(row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(relief='groove')
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(text='''Results Folder Location''') 
   

# %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
Button_OpenFile = tk.Button(ExtFrame)
Button_OpenFile.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Button_OpenFile.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
Button_OpenFile.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(compound='left')
Button_OpenFile.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
Button_OpenFile.configure(foreground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightcolor="black")
Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN FILE''')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I just added some modifications to your code, I added the `height` and `width` attributes for the `LabelFrame` object. Not sure why but without those attributes the LabelFrame is not being shown.

Line modified:

```
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.LabelFrame(ExtFrame, height=40,width=150)
```

Full Code:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

# %% ROOT
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("710x630+410+100")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.resizable(1,  1)
root.title("myGUI")
root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# %% EXTERNAL FRAME
ExtFrame = tk.Frame(root)
ExtFrame.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
#ExtFrame.configure(bg='blue')
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)


# %% RESULTS FOLDER LOCATION
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.LabelFrame(ExtFrame, height=40,width=150)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.grid(row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(relief='groove')
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(text='''Results Folder Location''') 
   

# %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
Button_OpenFile = tk.Button(ExtFrame)
Button_OpenFile.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Button_OpenFile.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
Button_OpenFile.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(compound='left')
Button_OpenFile.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
Button_OpenFile.configure(foreground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightcolor="black")
Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN FILE''')

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT:

New version without `LabelFrame` dimensions, I'll use a `Label` inside the `LabelFrame` to auto-expand it.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

# %% ROOT
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("710x630+410+100")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.resizable(1,  1)
root.title("myGUI")
root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# %% EXTERNAL FRAME
ExtFrame = tk.Frame(root)
ExtFrame.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
#ExtFrame.configure(bg='blue')
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)


# %% RESULTS FOLDER LOCATION
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.LabelFrame(ExtFrame)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.grid(row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(relief='groove')
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(text='''Results Folder Location''') 
Label_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.Label(Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation)
Label_ResultsFolderLocation.config(text='label to expand the LabelFrame')
Label_ResultsFolderLocation.pack()


   

# %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
Button_OpenFile = tk.Button(ExtFrame)
Button_OpenFile.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Button_OpenFile.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
Button_OpenFile.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(compound='left')
Button_OpenFile.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
Button_OpenFile.configure(foreground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightcolor="black")
Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN FILE''')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it appears. But it seems to me that it is like a place style of coding. I mean I would like that the layout manager takes all the widgets and display properly. If I have to set dimensions and/or positions I will use the place layout manager instead of grid. Is there a way to let the manager decide automatically? In this example dimensions are not define: [link](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-labelframe/)

Comment: @eljamba Hi, I just added at the end of my post a new version without the height and width. This new version uses a Label inside the LabelFrame, this Label makes the LabelFrame auto-expand to fit into the Label size.

Answer (score 1):

Your LabelFrame is displayed but has a size of 1 pixel. You can (hardly) see it if you make it a different color than your root widget `Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.LabelFrame(ExtFrame, bg='black')`:
[image]

You have to add some widget into the LabelFrame to see it, for example a button. Or you can explicitly set the size of the LabelFrame as you have already been answered.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.constants import *

# %% ROOT
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("710x630+410+100")
root.minsize(120, 1)
root.resizable(1, 1)
root.title("myGUI")
root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# %% EXTERNAL FRAME
ExtFrame = tk.Frame(root)
ExtFrame.place(relheight=1, relwidth=1)
# ExtFrame.configure(bg='blue')
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
ExtFrame.rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

# %% RESULTS FOLDER LOCATION
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation = tk.LabelFrame(ExtFrame)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.grid(row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(relief='groove')
Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation.configure(text='''Results Folder Location''')
SomeButton = tk.Button(Labelframe_ResultsFolderLocation,
                        text='Click me!').pack()

# %% BUTTON OPEN FILE
Button_OpenFile = tk.Button(ExtFrame)
Button_OpenFile.grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Button_OpenFile.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
Button_OpenFile.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(compound='left')
Button_OpenFile.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
Button_OpenFile.configure(foreground="#000000")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
Button_OpenFile.configure(highlightcolor="black")
Button_OpenFile.configure(text='''OPEN FILE''')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! I was drowning in a glass of water!